# mysqld.service failed on Amazon-linux -2

Tags: mysql, amazon-linux-2

I would like to install MySQL5.7 to my amazon linux in some way.
However I do not know that It is possible to install mysql5.7 in Amazon-linux.
Originally in my EC2 , Maria DB was set as default.
I did these steps.

But it did not start.

```
$ sudo yum install -y 
$ yum list installed | grep mysql
$ sudo yum-config-manager --disable mysql80-community
$ sudo yum-config-manager --enable mysql57-community

$ yum repolist all | grep -E "mysql[0-9]+-community/x86"
```

```
$ sudo yum install -y mysql-community-server
Loaded :extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
amzn2-core                                                                                                                                                  | 3.7 kB  00:00:00     
385 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Package mysql-community-server-5.7.36-1.el7.x86_64 is the latest version.
```

```
$ sudo systemctl start mysqld
Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

```
$ systemctl status mysqld.service
● mysqld.service - MySQL Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Fri 2021-12-10 20:52:34 JST; 26s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
  Process: 32505 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid $MYSQLD_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 32484 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

12- 10 20:52:34 ip-172-91-96-191.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: mysqld.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
12- 10 20:52:34 ip-172-91-96-191.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
12- 10 20:52:34 ip-172-91-96-191.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
12- 10 20:52:34 ip-172-91-96-191.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.
12- 10 20:52:34 ip-172-91-96-191.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: mysqld.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
12- 10 20:52:34 ip-172-91-96-191.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for mysqld.service
12- 10 20:52:34 ip-172-91-96-191.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
12- 10 20:52:34 ip-172-91-96-191.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
12- 10 20:52:34 ip-172-91-96-191.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.
```

I also did these steps.

I tried look up the way as far I can.

```
https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/
$ /etc/init.d/mysql stop
-bash: /etc/init.d/mysql: No such file or directory

$ service mysql stop
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl stop mysql.service
Failed to stop mysql.service: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files
See system logs and 'systemctl status mysql.service' for details.

$ killall -KILL mysql mysqld_safe mysqld
mysql: no process found
mysqld_safe: no process found
mysqld: no process found

$ /etc/init.d/mysql start
-bash: /etc/init.d/mysql: No such file or directory

$ sudo systemctl stop mysqld

$ sudo systemctl start mysqld
Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

```
$ sudo cat /var/log/mysqld.log
Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x40000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x3b)[0xf525bb]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x486)[0x7e3f06]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x117e0)[0x7f0dc34517e0]
/lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x110)[0x7f0dc1da0c20]
/lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x148)[0x7f0dc1da20c8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x7b3eb0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN2ib5fatalD1Ev+0xfd)[0x12882cd]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x133fce2]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x134022b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z6fil_ioRK9IORequestbRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_tmmPvS8_+0x208)[0x134baf8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z13buf_read_pageRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_t+0xe4)[0x12f9d74]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16buf_page_get_genRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_tmP11buf_block_tmPKcmP5mtr_tb+0x42d)[0x12c916d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z31trx_rseg_get_n_undo_tablespacesPm+0x15d)[0x126742d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x122f258]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z34innobase_start_or_create_for_mysqlv+0x3996)[0x12339a6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x10f8a2f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x51)[0x836df1]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xd35d35]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z40plugin_register_builtin_and_init_core_sePiPPc+0x2f0)[0xd3c060]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x7dc3e4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0xa85)[0x7dfc05]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xea)[0x7f0dc1d8e0ba]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x7d3864]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
2021-12-10T12:20:30.164676Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2021-12-10T12:20:30.171606Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.36) starting as process 1117 ...
2021-12-10T12:20:30.192632Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2021-12-10T12:20:30.192667Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2021-12-10T12:20:30.192671Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-12-10T12:20:30.192675Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2021-12-10T12:20:30.192678Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-12-10T12:20:30.192681Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2021-12-10T12:20:30.192972Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-12-10T12:20:30.193097Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2021-12-10T12:20:30.203486Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2021-12-10T12:20:30.218799Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-12-10T12:20:30.224633Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2021-12-10T12:20:30.252634Z 0 [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Table flags are 0 in the data dictionary but the flags in file ./ibdata1 are 0x4000!
2021-12-10 21:20:30 0x7f9a7c57d740  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140301487822656 in file ut0ut.cc line 921
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
12:20:30 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
collection process might fail.

key_buffer_size=8388608
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70304171/is-it-possible-to-install-mysql-5-7-to-amazon-linux-2?

Comment: Yes but that question was closed by Administrator

Comment: Did you read the reason? How does this question differ?